# Running Angular5 app locally against Azure AD protected backend

Tags: azure, angular5, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We have an Angular5 application with a DotNet OData backend API.  The application is hosted in a Web Application with a virtual directory for the Angular5 app and another virtual directory for the DotNet backend.  The web application is secured by Azure AD, with an Azure AD Application defined for the web site.

This all works perfectly.  We have no authentication code in the front end (except for 'withCredentials: true' set in the service calls) but apparently having the whole application protected by Azure AD makes the front end able to call the backend without issue (Azure makes you authenticate when you access the Angular5 front end).

The problem comes when we try to develop the front end.  When developing Angular5 one needs to run the Angular5 code locally, so I've set up a web app which hosts only the backend code and point the local configuration for the Angular5 app there.  This fails with the first backend call with a 401.  One of our developers discovered that if you simply plug in the URL to the backend with the same browser (i.e. copy the failing call from the browser network developer tab into a new browser tab in the same browser) you will go through the authentication process and then when you run the local Angular5 app again it works.  We thought we had found a workaround until we noticed that for some reason this only seems to fix the "read only" calls.  GET works, OPTIONS works but POST fails with a 401.  I put some debugging code in the backend but it seems this code does not even get called (i.e. Azure, not our backend, is blocking the call).

So I've tried to figure out how to get the local Angular5 instance to behave as the one hosted by the Web app but I can't figure out what I need to be doing.  I have also been unable to find anyone else doing this so I can't find a solution.

I have tried various solutions of actively getting a token (e.g. setting up /.auth/me, using adal5 to "login", etc.) for the front end but it seems every possible solution is defeated by CORS in the end.  Our backend has an Allow-Origin for localhost:4200 but this doesn't apply to login.windows.com for the authentication step.  I tried putting localhost:4200 in the CORS setting on the Azure Web App but then it complains about an Allow-Authentication header being missing and I have no way to force Azure to provide that.  I read online that this is happening because Azure didn't expect people to be using "cookie authentication" so after some research I found that "cookie authentication" was being used because of the "withCredentials: true" calls, so I changed all of those to false.  Then the Allow-Authentication failure goes away but I just run into more CORS failures during the authorisation (login.windows.com).

So I'm really stuck here.  I can't believe I'm the only person on earth who's trying to run a local instance of Angular5 against an Azure AD secured Azure Web app backend but I can't find any examples anywhere of people successfully doing this.  I also would like to avoid having to do some elaborate local authentication because the code works perfectly as-is when hosted on the same Azure Web app as the backend.  Does anyone have a setup like I describe that is working?

Comment: In your second paragraph, did you mean `withCredentials: true`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Fixed.